# What's the equivalent of Vue's Vuex in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am familiar with vue's vuex, but now I am working on angular application where I want apply same principle, all components will be managed from one place (store in Vue). Is some alternative for vuex in angular 2+? Thanks.

Comment: redux...........

Comment: flux in general

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/store

Answer (score 8):

You have multiple options when adding state management to an Angular application. I also came from a Vue background before diving into Angular. I recommend taking a look at NGXS, you'll find the concepts to be very similar to Vuex.

Comment: Hi, just a quick question, what made you transition from Vue to Angular?

Comment: @naz786 in my case im switching from Vue to Angular because it looks have a better support for typescript that i dont see even in nuxt.js. I had a bad experiêncice building a large application with pure javascript and today with a grpc server instead a rest API its possible to build an app closer to 100% type-safe